# How to expose package.json in angular app

Tags: javascript, angular, npm, angular-cli

I'm running my app with **ng serve** and am wondering if there is a way to fetch the package.json file inside my app.

My initial idea was to copy package.json to the folder **./dist** and read it from there but this seems to not be an option when using **ng serve**, which works in-memory and doesn't use the dist folder.

Is there a way to get the file when using ng serve or alternatively to make **ng serve** use the **dist** older instead of running in in-memory mode?

I am using Angular 4 and angular CLI version 1.3.2 (together with npm 4.3.0).

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to solve it by setting the **glob** property in the [project assets](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/stories-asset-configuration) configuration inside *.angular-cli.json*

```
  "apps": [
    {
      "root": "src",
      "outDir": "dist",
      "assets": [
        "assets",
        "favicon.ico",
        { "glob": "package.json", "input": "../", "output": "./assets/" }
      ],
    }
```

The solution allows the file to be available from the outside therefore making GET requests possible.

Answer (score 2):

What build mechanism are you using? If you're in something like webpack, with the appropriate loader you can do

```
import package from '../package.json';   //es6, or
var package = require('../package.json');  //commonJS

console.log( package.version );
```

This will bundle up the package.json file as part of your build step. This can also be done using Browserify (but you'll probably need a transform).